# Java Swing BorderLayout isn't displayed correctly

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, layout-manager, border-layout

When I try to compile the source code and run the program, sometimes everything seems fine and sometimes buttons are not correctly displayed.

Basically, there is a scaling issue. The fact of the matter is I don't understand why it works perfectly fine and sometimes just doesn't. Below you can see the source code and images.

I think the problem is with `Jpane` and `BorderLayout` but couldn't understand why exactly.

[image: Working GUI]

[image: Not correctly displayed one]

```
class PropertyPanel extends PartPanel {

  private Action actionLoadProp, actionSimProp;
  private JButton buttonLoadProp, buttonSimProp;
  private JTextField fieldProp;
  private PropertiesFile m_propertiesFile;
  private PropertiesList listProp;
  private PropConstPanel mdPp;
  private boolean selectedProp;

  PropertyPanel(Config config) {
    super(config);
    selectedProp = false;
    initActions();
    initGUIComp();

  }

  void initGUIComp() {
    buttonLoadProp = new JButton(actionLoadProp);
    buttonSimProp = new JButton(actionSimProp);
    fieldProp = new JTextField(35);

    JPanel panelMainProp = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(5, 5));
    listProp = new PropertiesList();

    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(listProp);
    panelMainProp.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Properties"));

    JPanel panelProp = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEADING));
    panelProp.add(fieldProp);
    panelProp.add(buttonLoadProp);
    panelProp.add(buttonSimProp);
    panelMainProp.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    panelMainProp.add(panelProp, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    PropertyPanel.this.add(panelMainProp, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    mdPp = new PropConstPanel();
    PropertyPanel.this.add(mdPp, BorderLayout.CENTER);
  }

  String getProperty(int index) {
    if (m_propertiesFile != null)
      return ((Expression) m_propertiesFile.getProperty(index))
        .toString();

    return "";
  }

  private void initActions() {
    actionLoadProp = new AbstractAction("Load Properties") {

      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        loadProp();

      }

    };

    actionSimProp = new AbstractAction("Simulate") {

      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

        m_config.propId = -1;
        UndefinedConstants consts = new UndefinedConstants(m_config.getModel(), null);

        ConstTableModel modelTable = ExperimentSetup.getInstance()
          .getMf_constModel();
        int size = modelTable.getRowCount();
        try {
          String constName, constValue;
          int type;
          for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            constName = modelTable.getConstant(i).name;
            constValue = "" + modelTable.getConstant(i).value;
            type = consts.getMFUndefinedType(i);
            consts.defineConstant(constName,
              "" + mdPp.parseValue(type, constValue));

          }
          consts.checkAllDefined();
          consts.initialiseIterators();
          m_config.getModel().setUndefinedConstants(
            consts.getMFConstantValues());
        } catch (PrismException e) {
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage(), "Constant error", JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION);
          return;
        }
        consts.initialiseIterators();
        ExperimentSetup.getInstance().simulateCX();
      }
    };

  }
  class PropConstPanel extends ConstPanel {

    private UndefinedConstants unDefConst;

    public PropConstPanel() {
      super("Property Constants");
    }

    public void fillTables() {
      ExperimentSetup setup = ExperimentSetup.getInstance();

      unDefConst = new UndefinedConstants(m_config.getModel(),
        m_propertiesFile);
      for (int i = 0; i < unDefConst.getPFNumUndefined(); i++) {
        modelTableConst.addConstant(unDefConst.getPFUndefinedName(i),
          unDefConst.getPFUndefinedType(i), "");
      }
      setup.enableNext();
    }

    public boolean checkValidity() {
      // return (unDefConst.getPFNumUndefined() > 0) ? false : true;
      return !modelTableConst.isUnDefConstInTable();
    }

    public void parseConstants() {
      ConstTableModel propTableConst = getModelTable();
      ConstTableModel modelTable = ExperimentSetup.getInstance()
        .getMf_constModel();
      int size = modelTable.getRowCount();
      try {
        String constName, constValue;
        int type;
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
          constName = modelTable.getConstant(i).name;
          constValue = "" + modelTable.getConstant(i).value;
          type = unDefConst.getMFUndefinedType(i);
          unDefConst.defineConstant(constName,
            "" + parseValue(type, constValue));

        }
        size = propTableConst.getRowCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
          constName = propTableConst.getConstant(i).name;
          constValue = "" + propTableConst.getConstant(i).value;
          type = unDefConst.getPFUndefinedType(i);
          unDefConst.defineConstant(constName,
            "" + parseValue(type, constValue));

        }

        unDefConst.checkAllDefined();
        unDefConst.initialiseIterators();

        m_propertiesFile.setUndefinedConstants(unDefConst
          .getPFConstantValues());
        m_config.getModel().setUndefinedConstants(
          unDefConst.getMFConstantValues());
        m_config.setProp(m_propertiesFile);
      } catch (PrismException e) {
        Registry.getMain().handleWarning(e.getMessage());
      }

    }

  }

  package dipro.run.wizard;

  import java.awt.BorderLayout;

  import javax.swing.JPanel;

  import parser.ast.ModulesFile;
  import parser.ast.PropertiesFile;

  import dipro.run.Config;

  public abstract class PartPanel extends JPanel {

    Config m_config;
    ModulesFile m_modulesFiles;

    public PartPanel(Config config) {
      m_config = config;
      setLayout(new BorderLayout(5, 5));

    }

    abstract boolean isValidConf();

    abstract void parseConstants();


    public Config getConfig() {
      return m_config;
    }
  }
```

Comment: @Java what do you mean exactly?

Comment: Which layout manager is using for PropertyPanel

Comment: @Java Borderlayout

Comment: @theroglu Please keep your question as minimal as possible, avoid adding unnecessary sentences that take longer for an answerer to read and provide an answer. Just state the problem and provide an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I have done this for you this time.

Comment: @MasterYoda Great suggestion, and a tip: `[mcve]` in a comment auto-expands to [mcve].

Comment: @AndrewThompson Great tip, thank you :)